# Visual Studio Code terminal is not displaying script failure (failure block) error message and its details

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Failures:

Message:
   Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, xyz)
 Stack:
4 specs, 2 failures
Finished in 39.887 seconds

While testing angularjs website using protractor in java script, Above lines are not displaying if script is failing.
Hence I am not able to find the reason of script failure, it was working previously.
Please let me know if there is any setting for terminal.
TIA

Comment: So, you are getting this error message? Your element is not displaying on the page or you have timing issues. 
Fixxes: 1. scroll to your element before you access it 2. implemented browser.wait or browser.sleep (not recommended) 3. adjust your protractor settings with asynchronous websites

Comment: No, I am not getting this error message. Terminal is not displaying any error message. I captured above error message from another VS Code setup by running same script. I want to see this error message in my VS code setup after script failure.

Comment: This worked for me...In conf.js file, inside export.config object,
check for these lines. These lines are responsible for showing an error message.                                                                      
           jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true, 
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }